# Is there any way to use a GIFs in the title bar?

Tags: html, web

I really want a moving logo for my website. Is there any way I could make the logo on top in the browser tab a GIF using HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to work on most browsers, you need to "manually" switch the images

```
var favicon_images = [
                    'http://website.com/img/tmp-0.gif',
                    'http://website.com/img/tmp-1.gif',
                    'http://website.com/img/tmp-2.gif',
                    'http://website.com/img/tmp-3.gif',
                    'http://website.com/img/tmp-4.gif',
                    'http://website.com/img/tmp-5.gif',
                    'http://website.com/img/tmp-6.gif'
                ],
    image_counter = 0; // To keep track of the current image

setInterval(function() {
    // remove current favicon
    if(document.querySelector("link[rel='icon']") !== null)
        document.querySelector("link[rel='icon']").remove();
    if(document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']") !== null)
        document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']").remove();
        
    // add new favicon image
    document.querySelector("head").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '');
    
    // If last image then goto first image
    // Else go to next image    
    if(image_counter == favicon_images.length -1)
        image_counter = 0;
    else
        image_counter++;
}, 200);
```

You can see this working here: https://usefulangle.com/post/45/animate-favicon-gif-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try using a gif as icon

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/gif" />
```